# Lock/Unlock of the parameter (Check), Check if the value of parameter is set from KWA Rule (Edit Window for CADPRT)

Tags: vba, catia

```
Catia V5 R24

1) is there any way to check by the VBA code if the parameter in catia is locked ? 
2) Is there any way to check by the VBA code if the value of the parameter is set from the KWA rule ?
```

What I'm going to do:
I will have a Catia Part with necessary geometry, parameters and rules in KWA.
I will add only in VBA window where user can easily edit and modify a geometry.
Below You can find a sample How it will looks like
[image]

1. User Will chose a method for the calculation parameter (3 and 4)
2. if he will chose 1st (script will check if the parameter in PRT file has a lock status, and if it is set from the KWA Rule) if yes than script should change a window option (Enabled > False, disable a posililiby to put any values to this window), and Enable button 2

I know that there will be more problems with this window, but I will try to solve them one by one.

Here is my test code

```
    Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    
Call ChangeValue("Show_Window", "No")
     Me.Hide
     'End


End Sub



Public Sub Start_Click()

On Error Resume Next
Set curDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
Set mySel = curDoc.Selection
mySel.Search "Name= 'xy plane', in"
If TypeName(curDoc) = "PartDocument" Then Set curPrt = curDoc.Part
If TypeName(curDoc) = "ProductDocument" Then Set curPrt = mySel.FindObject("CATIAPart")


Set ihybBodies = curPrt.HybridBodies
Set ihybBody = curPrt.InWorkObject
Dim iPars As Parameters: Set iPars = curPrt.Parameters
Dim iPar As Parameter


'search parameters length
mySel.Clear: mySel.Add ihybBody: mySel.Search "Name=Length_Param,in"
Set iPar = mySel.Item2(1).Value: LengthParam = iPar.Value & " mm"

  

'search parameters length 2nd method
Set iPar = Parameters.Item("Length_Param").Value: Length2ndMethod = iPar.Value & " mm"

'check lock status
 Dim myLockStatus As Boolean
    myLockStatus = Parameters.LockStatus("Length_Param").Lock
    
    MsgBox myLockStatus
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'search string
mySel.Clear: mySel.Add ihybBody: mySel.Search "Name=String Param,in"
Set iPar = mySel.Item2(1).Value: StringParam = iPar.Value
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'search ListBox
mySel.Clear: mySel.Add ihybBody: mySel.Search "Name=String_List,in"
Set iPar = mySel.Item2(1).Value

'Clear List
 ListBox.Clear


'Add Items to list from CADPRT
cnt = iPar.GetEnumerateValuesSize

Dim ParamValues() As Variant

ReDim ParamValues(cnt)
iPar.GetEnumerateValues ParamValues

        For i = 0 To cnt - 1
           With ListBox
           .AddItem ParamValues(i)
           End With
        Next
        
'set value from PRT
ListBox = iPar.Value
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

End Sub
```

Comment: Were you planning on including the relevant part of the code? or...

Comment: At this moment I have only a test code which is loading a values from the PRT

Comment: It is unlikely you are going to find catia experts readily available here, so the way you are asking your question is unlikely to get you any results. Stack Overflow is more for "here is my code and i am having this issue" type questions. In other words, your question is most likely going to be considered "too broad" and get closed otherwise.

Comment: If you are going to add code, make sure you add it to the question and not as a comment.

Comment: I know that "C R Johnson" can answer for my question but there is no way to communicate with him direct :( 
And I have been searching an answer for those 2 questions at meany forums.
OK, next time I will try to use less words. I just wanted describe what kind of problem I have